# Function saying i cannot redeclare php

Tags: php, fatal-error

I am working with an API that has a function called invokeGetMatchingProductForId() and every time the script is run, this error occurs. I am attempting to loop through the script to change one variable but i am not sure if that is the problem. If you guys have any suggestions let me know. Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks in advance!

```
  function invokeGetMatchingProductForId(MarketplaceWebServiceProducts_Interface $service, $request)
  {
  try {
    $response = $service->GetMatchingProductForId($request);

    echo ("Service Response\n");
    echo ("=============================================================================\n");
      global $file_name;
      global $i;
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadXML($response->toXML());
    $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    $dom->formatOutput = true;
    echo $dom->saveXML();
    $dom ->save('xml/' . $file_name . $i . '.xml');  
    echo("ResponseHeaderMetadata: " . $response->getResponseHeaderMetadata() . "\n");

 } catch (MarketplaceWebServiceProducts_Exception $ex) {
    echo("Caught Exception: " . $ex->getMessage() . "\n");
    echo("Response Status Code: " . $ex->getStatusCode() . "\n");
    echo("Error Code: " . $ex->getErrorCode() . "\n");
    echo("Error Type: " . $ex->getErrorType() . "\n");
    echo("Request ID: " . $ex->getRequestId() . "\n");
    echo("XML: " . $ex->getXML() . "\n");
    echo("ResponseHeaderMetadata: " . $ex-    >getResponseHeaderMetadata() . "\n");
 }
 }
```

When I get a response from the server, This error occurs.

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare function()(previously declared in x:\xampp\htdocs\name\src\project0\php\unknown.php:110) in x:\xampp\htdocs\name\src\project0\php\unknown.php on line 136
```

Line 136 is an empty line.

Comment: pretty much self-explanatory, wouldn't you say? without source code, we can't be of any help here.

Comment: I will edit it with the source code.

Comment: *"I am working with an API that has a function called `invokeMatchingId()`"* - Your code doesn't support the question.

Comment: Fixed the name of the function.

Comment: look at this `functioninvokeGetMatchingProductForId` is that your real code? If it is, it's missing  a space here `function invokeGetMatchingProductForId` and is most likely the reason why you're getting that error.

Comment: in my code, it does have the space. I am not sure why it didnt show here.

Comment: again, you have one body of code with that function name, but not showing us the rest of your code, if it's an include, calling the same function from another file.... could be anything.

Comment: and I see `function invokeGetMatchingProductForId` then `$service->GetMatchingProductForId` - sorry, but your question is too unclear. Good luck, I sincerely hope you find your solution.

Comment: i am working with the amazon API, and this is what they have provided me with. I am just attempting to modify the code to make it work.

Comment: What line is `unknown.php` line 110?

Comment: You can try, if(function_exists('invokeGetMatchingProductForId')){}

Comment: i got it to work with the if statement, but when i put an else it returns that value too. Can someone explain?

Comment: line 110 Is the top of the code that i provided.